# Sort of text file in python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I have  text file customer.text

`Customer.text`:

```
3|jack|USA
1|Maria|China
2|Kaishik|India
```

I want to sort this table with column1. after the sorting it should be look like this

```
1|Maria|China
2|Kaishik|India
3|jack|USA
```

I am new in python I tried some of  `data.sort(data, key=lambda data: data[0])` method but it doesn't work for me. I am really stuck with this sort function.

Comment: How do you read the file?

Comment: What is `data` here? Can you tell us **how** it doesn't work for you? Please include a code sample, and any (full) error messages you got, or the unexpected output otherwise.

Comment: use pandas package for these tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'pandas' package for these tasks.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('customer.txt',delimiter='|', header = None)
df.sort([0])

        0   1   2
   1    1   Maria   China
   2    2   Kaishik India
   0    3   jack    USA
```

Comment: -0. Not incorrect, but seems a bit heavy weight.

Comment: I suppose that depends on OPs needs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `data` is a list of lists, with the first "column" being the number as an `int`, your sort should work. Note, however, that you are mixing the syntax for `sort` and `sorted`!

Using `sort`, you do not need to pass `data` as another parameter; it is implicitly passed as the `self` paremeter. Just use `data.sort(key=lambda d: d[0])` to sort `data` in-place. If you want to create a sorted (shallow) copy of `data`, use `data2 = sorted(data, key=lambda d: d[0])`.

```
text = """3|jack|USA
1|Maria|China
2|Kaishik|India"""
data = [line.split("|") for line in text.splitlines()]
data = [[int(i), name, state] for i, name, state in data]
data.sort(key=lambda d: d[0])
```

After this, `data` is `[[1, 'Maria', 'China'], [2, 'Kaishik', 'India'], [3, 'jack', 'USA']]`

Comment: `sorted(data, key=lambda d: d[0])` won't work on ny double digit numbers

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Could you elaborate? Why shouldn't it work? Works fine for me. Note that I'm casting to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`sort`  is a list method, you don't pass the list in, you call the method on the list.

```
 with open("in.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split("|")[0]))
    print(data)

['1|Maria|China\n', '2|Kaishik|India\n', '3|jack|USA\n']
```

`key=lambda x: int(x.split("|")[0])` splits each row on `|` and sorts based on the first element, which is the number.

If you want to write the updated values to the file:

```
with open("in.txt","r+") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split("|")[0]))
    f.seek(0) # go back to start of the file
    for line in data:
        f.write(line) # write new data
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply sort the list:

```
file = open("Customer.text", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
lines.sort()
file.close()
```

See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Comment: As tobias_k stated in his answer sort() only works, if you split the lines and have the number as int

Comment: This does not work because e.g. `"10|"` will be sorted before `"1|"` as `ord("0") < ord("|")`

Comment: KillianDS: Yes, I just realized that, see the comment. Upvoted tobias_k's answer